What is causing the cats' spontaneous aggression after being hurt?
My friend and I moved in together and she brought her two cats. The other day, a kid was brought to the house, and for some reason, the cats started attacking the kid when he was left alone. Not knowing what was happening I grabbed the cats and held them to the ground to protect the kid. Once he was safe, I released the cats and one went to attack me so I slapped it on the head and left the house with the kid. I came back to the house later and the cats were uneasy with me but let me pet them and were friendly.
The next day service guys were coming over and I put the cat that was assumed to have initiated the attack in the bathroom (the same cat I slapped). Then after a bit of waiting, I walked to the front door, and the other cat which was letting me pet it moments before hissed and jumped to attack me. I threw my blanket around it and held it down until my friend got out of the house. I quickly got up and exited out the front door. Since the service guys were now pulling up I had to go back in and move the cat. I had to grab it with a blanket which it tried attacking me again of course and put it in the garage but now I don't know what to do.
I might be the only one they turn aggressive on but I don't want to risk that with my friend and her daughter in the house. My friend is devastated about the thought of removing the cats but I don't know how to trust them or even regain their trust. What should I do?

How long ago did you move to the new house? It's perfectly normal for cats to be uneasy for several weeks after moving. This sounds like their anxiety boils over into attacking.

Over a month ago.

How did you prepare the area for the cats,Did you bring toys,Cat furniture,food and water bowls to the nrw house,Do the cats have any elevated hiding places so they can feel safe from people getting too close.When you move with a cat you should bring some of your cats stuff like a cat bed and other objects that has the cats scent on it.
